# How can I get rewards into payment address?

Tags: transaction, cardano-cli, utxo, rewards, staking

I have stake pool `paymentwithstake.addr` which is a composition of `payment.addr` with `stake.addr`.

I can query `stake.addr` for the balance using the following command:

```
cardano-cli query stake-address-info --mainnet --address $(cat stake.addr)
```

From the outcome, I can see there is available `rewardAccountBalance`.

The question is:

How can I move reward to my `payment.addr` aka transform in a UTXO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of moving your rewards (account balance system) to your payment address (UTXO balance system) is called reward withdrawal.

As per [withdraw-rewards.md](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/stake-pool-operations/withdraw-rewards.md):

#### Check the balance of the rewards address:

```
cardano-cli query stake-address-info \
--mainnet \
--address $(cat stake.addr)

[
    {
        "address": "stake_test1urxx5h9mhey1234566ek6uxqgtlkpvteqjqgaleddevpggfggxw",
        "delegation": "pool1ljq292q5xwz8t3ehmaw3c5p9xpr123456dnrxd40004ns6dy8v0",
        "rewardAccountBalance": 550000000
    }
]
```

#### Query the payment address balance

You'll withdraw rewards into a payment.addr wich will pay for the transaction fees.

```
cardano-cli query utxo --mainnet --address $(cat payment.addr)

                           TxHash                                 TxIx         Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a82f8d2a85cde39118a894306ad7a85ba40af221406064a56bdd9b3c61153527     1         194054070 lovelace
```

#### Draft the withdraw transaction to transfer the rewards to a payment.addr

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in a82f8d2a85cde39118a894306ad7a85ba40af221406064a56bdd9b3c61153527#1 \
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+0 \
--withdrawal $(cat stake.addr)+0 \
--invalid-hereafter 0 \
--fee 0 \
--out-file withdraw_rewards.draft
```

#### Calculate transaction fees

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
--tx-body-file withdraw_rewards.draft  \
--tx-in-count 1 \
--tx-out-count 1 \
--witness-count 2 \
--byron-witness-count 0 \
--mainnet \
--protocol-params-file protocol.json
```

> 171089

#### Build the raw transaction.

```
expr 194054070 - 171089 + 550000000
743882981

cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in a82f8d2a85cde39118a894306ad7a85ba40af221406064a56bdd9b3c61153527#1 \
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+743882981 \
--withdrawal $(cat stake.addr)+550000000 \
--invalid-hereafter 12345678 \
--fee 171089 \
--out-file withdraw_rewards.raw
```

#### Sign and submit the transactions

```
cardano-cli transaction sign \
--tx-body-file withdraw_rewards.raw  \
--signing-key-file payment.skey \
--signing-key-file stake.skey \
--mainnet \
--out-file withdraw_rewards.signed

cardano-cli transaction submit \
--tx-file withdraw_rewards.signed \
--mainnet
```